# Проверка возраста и пола через select

Tags: html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 чекБоекса и 1 селект. Нужно, чтобы при выборе "М" или "Ж", а также при выборе определённого возраста всплывал alert. Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Выберите пол:
М<input type="checkbox" name="me" id="men">
Ж<input type="checkbox" name="wu" id="wum">
<br/>
Выберите возраст: <select id="mySelect">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>23</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>25</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Рассчитать</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {

var v = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;

if (v<11) {alert("Подросток");} else 
if ($('#men').prop('checked') && v>12 && v<20) {alert("Юноша");} else 
if ($('#men').prop('checked') && v>20) {alert("Мужчина");} else 
if ($("#wum").prop("checked") && v>12 && v<20) {alert("Девушка");} else 
if ($("#wum").prop("checked") && v>20) {alert("Женщина");}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Кто скажет, в чём ошибка? Alert не появляется вообще. Но если из ветвления убрать проверку чекБокса, то всё работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает, потому для проверки чекбокса вы используете jquery, но при этом не подключаете файл jquery. Ниже код с подключенным файлом jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  Выберите пол: М
  <input type="checkbox" name="me" id="men">Ж
  <input type="checkbox" name="wu" id="wum">
  <br/>Выберите возраст:
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
  </select>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Рассчитать</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var v = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;

      if (v < 11) {
        alert("Подросток");
      } else if ($('#men').prop('checked') && v > 12 && v < 20) {
        alert("Юноша");
      } else if ($('#men').prop('checked') && v > 20) {
        alert("Мужчина");
      } else if ($("#wum").prop("checked") && v > 12 && v < 20) {
        alert("Девушка");
      } else if ($("#wum").prop("checked") && v > 20) {
        alert("Женщина");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Всё заработало!